# specify range in XML element

Tags: xml

For xml elements, is there a way to specify a range of values for an element? for example, if this is part of my xml my xml:

```
<store>
     <price1>1-2</price1> **
     <price2>2.34</price2>
</store>
```

**Is there a way to do this or would I have to do something like this:

```
<store>
    <price1>1</prince1>
    <price1>2</prince1>
    <price2>2.34</prince2>
</store>
```

Thank you

Comment: You might be able to specify the range of value in XML schema... otherwise, write your own app logic to check for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML provides little more than elements, attributes and text. It is up to the software consuming the XML to determine the meaning of them.

So XML provides no barriers to writing `1-2` in a text node, but it is up to the software that reads it to determine that `1-2` represents a range.

A more XMLy approach might be to say:

```
<price1>
    <from>1</from>
    <to>2</to>
</price1>
```

… but again, the software consuming it would have to understand the from and to elements.